# How do I prove that this sequence is increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $a_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( \frac{1}{a_k} \right)^i$ for $a_k \neq 0$, how do I show that $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$ (strictly) increases as $k\in\mathbb{N}$ increases? I've tried induction but I just can't seem to get a solid solution.

Edit: yes, I meant $a_k$ in the sum. For example, for $k=3$ we have $a_3 = \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^1 + \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^2$. $a_3$ is the positive solution to this equation (in this case, the only solution).

Comment: ...$a_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( \frac{1}{a_k} \right)^i$ for $a_k \neq 0,$ ... I am having trouble understanding this specification.  Suppose that $k = 2$.  Then, according to your specification, $$a_2 = \left( \frac{1}{a_2} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{1}{a_2} \right)^1.$$  Please re-check your posting.

Comment: Assuming the $a_k$ in the summand is meant to be an $a_i,$ and that we define the beginning of the sequence just by providing $a_0,$ it seems that we always have $a_1 = 1$ and beyond that the sequence will always progress in the same manner

Comment: No, your first interpretation was correct. $a_2 = \left( \frac{1}{a_2} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{1}{a_2} \right)^1$ is correct. $a_2$ is the solution to this equation (in this case it is a quadratic).

Comment: Similarly, $a_3$ is the solution to $a_3 = \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^0 + \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^1 + \left( \frac{1}{a_3} \right)^2$, a cubic equation. I meant $a_k$ in the sum, not $a_i$.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but it's pretty easy to show that $a_k$ is given as a solution (I don't think $a_k$ is uniquely defined here also, which is a problem) to the equation $$a_k^k-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_k^j=0.$$